# Antd Table horizontal scroll

Tags: reactjs, antd

Actual Result:
Antd table horizontal scroll disappears on some resolutions.
[video](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/23411888?key=8760a68d2ee421370b660ac8dd78c979)

```
sticky={{
        offsetHeader: 0,
        offsetScroll: 0,
        getContainer: () => document.querySelector('.product-database-table-body')
      }}
```

Expected:
Horizontal scroll remains on any resolution

Antd - 5.2.2
React - 18.2

I have tried different ways of customizing this prop and sccrollbar itself, but none of these are working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can Set a fixed value for `scroll.x`to a fixed value rather than `true`. This will set a minimum width for the table and allow horizontal scrolling when the table width exceeds the container width:

```
<Table
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={data}
  scroll={{ x: '1500px' }}
/>
```

You can use `rc-resize-observer` to dynamically calculate the size of your container and set the `scroll` prop accordingly:

```
import ResizeObserver from 'rc-resize-observer';

// ...

<ResizeObserver
  onResize={({ width }) => {
    setTableWidth(width);
  }}
>
  <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    scroll={{ x: tableWidth }}
  />
</ResizeObserver>
```

Lastly if not all columns have a fixed width, horizontal scrolling may not work correctly, so add a fixed width:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    width: 200, // set a fixed width
    // ...
  },
  // ...
];
```

as a last resort you might need to use custom CSS to force the appearance of scroll bars:

```css
.table-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```
<div className="table-container">
  <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    scroll={{ x: 'max-content' }}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: In my example there were following props:
- scroll={{ x: 2100 }};
- all columns have fixed width;
- overflow: auto on a table container;
The problem is that at a 90% scale horizontal scrollbar is removed from the layout in the inspector => there is some condition under the hood of antd, that determines whether to display scrollbar or not

Comment: you could use ref to manually controlling the scrollbar position:`const handleScrollLeft = () => {
  tableContainerRef.current.scrollLeft -= 100;
};

const handleScrollRight = () => {
  tableContainerRef.current.scrollLeft += 100;
};`